# Is the following expression correct and idiomatic?

Tags: grammar, word-choice

If it's not correct or idiomatic, can you please mention which would be the best way to say that we don't want the second person to be sorry.

> "Brother, no need to be apologetic"

Comment: Appreciate your effort to help me out. Thank You @user121863

Comment: More common is "_no need to apologize_".